# Openvpn routing for lan to lan through tun

Tags: firewall, routing, openvpn, nat, site-to-site-vpn

I am trying to setup an OpenVPN tun to connect two lan's

The open vpn connection is up and working but there is a problem with my routing or nat or something.

What I need is an example of what a working, routed openvpn setup should look like on the server and client side. Mainly routing tables, Nat translation, firewalls etc.

Here is what I have working:
[image]

My OpenVPN Client can access the network on the server side but my server can't even ping my OpenVpn Client's `eth0`

My Servers routing:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.4.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0`

My Clients routing:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 3g-wan
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 3g-wan
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0`

This is automatically setup by openvpn using the:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0

and iroute command in the client-config-dir

If anyone can suggest something I need to check I would be very grateful
Alex

Edit 1#

OpenVPN Server Config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/mom_server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/mom_server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
client-to-client
route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
chroot /etc/openvpn
group nogroup
daemon
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

In /etc/openvpn/ccd/flexo_client

```
iroute 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
```

Edit 2#

I have this working, see here for the solution:

https://forums.openvpn.net/topic15768.html

Comment: Please post the solution from the openvpn forums as an answer here and accept it, in the spirit of sharing and being a good SF citizen. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

OP posted the answer on [forums.openvpn.net](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=15768#p41027)

---

Use this server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

topology subnet
mode server
tls-server

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt # flexo_client,10.8.0.4

client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client

#ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.4
route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.4

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/mom_server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/mom_server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem

keepalive 10 120i

comp-lzo

user nobody
chroot /etc/openvpn
group nogroup
daemon

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

With this /etc/openvpn/ccd/flexo_client

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1"
iroute 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
```

and this client config:

```
config openvpn 'flexo_client'
   option nobind '1'
   option float '1'
   option client '1'
   option comp_lzo '1'
   option dev 'tun0'
   option verb '3'
   option persist_tun '1'
   option persist_key '1'
   option remote_cert_tls 'server'
   option remote 'x.x.x.x'
   option proto 'udp'
   option resolv_retry 'infinite'
   option ca '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
   option cert '/etc/openvpn/flexo_client.crt'
   option key '/etc/openvpn/flexo_client.key'
   option ns_cert_type 'server'
   option topology 'subnet'
   option enable '1'
```

---

More information on using [OpenVPN and iroute](http://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/) can be found on backreference.org

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem where I was able to connect initially from server to client but after some time of inactivity I lose this ability.
I am using

static key, p2p toplogy, udp protocol and TUN

I've fixed the problem by adding

```
keepalive 20 120
```

to both server and client.
This will cause a ping being sent every 20 second and connection is assumed to be dropped if 120 second passed without a reply.